# setTimeout method executing one time

Tags: javascript, settimeout

When I click the checkBox, the function hesitates 5 seconds, and then rapidly loops through $.each skipping the setTimeout method. I assumed setTimeout would delay 5 seconds on each pass of the $.each loop? How can I make that so? Thanks

```
    checkBox.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var countLoop = 0;            
            $.each(placeObject, function(key,value) {
                setTimeout(function() {placesSearch(key,value);}, 5000);
                console.log("Loop :" + countLoop++);                
            });         
        }, 
        false);
```

Comment: You can't pause in JavaScript. The `setTimeout()` function establishes an action that will happen the given number of milliseconds in the future, but it returns immediately.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` returns the ID of the timeout, and does so immediately. It queues the action to be executed at a set time in the future. It won't actually pause the execution of the code it resides in, however, due to the immediate return.

If you want the code in `$.each` to be run after a pause, all of the code within the `$.each` needs to be wrapped with the `setTimeout`

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. I was under the impression it delayed it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/6dzp1sj7/1/

```
checkBox.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var countLoop = 0;

            $.each(placeObject, function(key,value) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    placesSearch(key,value);
                    console.log("Loop :" + countLoop++);
                }, (5000 * (key + 1)));           
            });         
        }, 
        false);
```

**Here is some JS KungFU for you:**
Here is its **fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/6dzp1sj7/3/

```
        var placeObject = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

        var countLoop = 0;         

        function tmp (key, value) {
                console.log(key);
                console.log(value);
                console.log("Loop :" + countLoop++);
        }

        var code = "";

        $.each(placeObject, function(key,value) {             
            var tmpl = "setTimeout(function() {tmp(" + key + ", " + value + ");__##__}, 1000);";

            if (key == 0) code = tmpl;

            if (key != 0) {
                code = code.replace('__##__', tmpl);
            }

            if (key == (placeObject.length - 1)) {
                code = code.replace('__##__', '');
                //console.log(code);
                eval(code);
            }                               
        });
```

**Note**: Never use a jack-hammer to drill just a hole.

Comment: How does this help, doesn't this just include the console statements? It still delays 1x and then rapidly loops there after.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each to fire within 5 seconds of one another, i.e. first iteration fires 5 seconds later, second iteration fires 10 seconds later, etc.. Then you need to multiply the delay of each individual timeout via the count index.

```
var countLoop = 1;            
$.each(placeObject, function(key,value) {
  setTimeout(function() {placesSearch(key,value);}, 5000*countLoop);
  console.log("Loop :" + countLoop++);                
});
```

I've created a demo that also illustrates how the scope would affect the values you are printing out with `console.log()`. See this fiddle for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/smtryj6s/6/

Comment: I edited my code and it is working, mostly. For some reason it keeps printing to console "Loop : 32" (There are 32 items in my placeObject)

Comment: @wannabe_n00b Try http://jsfiddle.net/skno39yh/1/ , without `value = key;` piece . If 32 items in `placeObject` , `index` (`key`) not 31 (0-31) ?

Comment: @wannabe_n00b Can you post a snippet of your code now? The code executing in the will rely on its parent 'scope' so if console.log(countLoop) is inside if of the timeout it will already be 32 by the time the code is executed. Does that make sense? If you wanted console.log to log the correct iteration you'd need to assign it to a temporary variable. See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smtryj6s/5/ (does this answer your question?)

Comment: I mistakenly used countLoop to set value, it works great now. Thanks. The setTimeout has allowed me to use the Google Maps API now. I was getting rejected previously for making requests too quickly

Comment: No problem! If I answered your Q please don't forget to mark my answer as the correct solution :)